# Can I use a portable dehumidifier as a temporary solution for the humidity in my crawlspace?

Tags: crawlspace, humidity, dehumidifier

I have a [Frigidaire 70 Pint Capacity Dehumidifier](https://support.frigidaire.com/Owner-Center/Product-Support/FFAD7033R1) that I'm considering putting down in my crawl space as a temporary solution.

Back story: Our house is only a 1.5 years old but the crawl space is very humid. I've seen it as high as 90% so I'm concerned about mold. Also our HVAC unit is always sweating down there leaving small puddles on the vapor barrier. The grading around the house seems to be ok but from what I understand, the soil in our neighborhood is just not great.

I have gotten a few quotes on installing a permanent dehumidifier (and sealing up all the vents) but it is a bit higher than I want to pay at the moment. We're heading into cooler weather so I'm hoping to put a bandaid on until we can do the full solution.

Is it a bad idea to use this dehumidifier in the crawl space. Was thinking I could get it up on cinder blocks so the gravity drain could go out where the AC condensate lines go out. Alternatively I could just empty out the bucket daily but that would obviously be a pain. Also, there is an outlet down there that the tankless natural gas hot water heater is plugged into. I wouldn't think it has a high amp draw so wondering if I can share that outlet for the dehumidifier. Obviously the ideal solution would be for it to have it's own circuit but again, this solution would be temporary.

1. Can I use this dehumidifier in the crawl space?
2. Can I share the outlet that the tankless gas is currently plugged into for the dehumidifier?

Comment: You probably can, but just wondering if the space is vented and if it is vented, have you tried running one or two fans down there to move the humid air out.  Just that fans much cheaper to run,

Comment: Yes there are vents, I've kept them closed year round at the advice of the builder and others. I've been told if they're open and there is mold, mold spores will just get blown all around and spread faster.

Comment: Is the outside air very humid?  With the vents closed and no air movement, no wonder you have high humidity down there.  Mold likes moisture, once it dries down, the mold dies.  I would open those vents and run a fan for a few days and see if it does not dry up.  As Colonel Potter use to say, I think you been told a bunch of horse hockey.

Comment: Mold spores are pretty much everywhere, all the time. Closing the vents is not likely to keep them out.

Comment: We live in a very humid climate. I believe the modern line of thought is to seal up the crawlspace and keep it dehumidified. The homerun solution being to fully encapsulate with a dehumidifier.

Comment: @Andrew Are you living in an area with 90% humidity? That's what in your crawlspace so why not try using the vent and fan first and see if that helps? The outside also has weather cycles so I can't imagine it being 90% for 24 hours straight.

Also, are your outside walls as moldy as your crawlspace? If your outside is just as humid, then your entire house should be moldy everywhere, not just the crawlspace. If the rest of your house is fine, but only your crawlspace is moldy, then it is due to lack of ventilation.

Comment: @Nelson would you recommend blowing outside air in with the fan, or inside air out? Also, there's no mold as far as I know... just trying to keep it that way.

Comment: @Andrew blowing inside air out makes the most sense to reduce bugs and rain, like a ventilator.